What does Backward Time Factor mean physically?
I'm fresh in Photonic Time Crystal research, struggling with the physical origin of Time Reflection.
Like what would happen at a spatial boundary, where an initial beam split into reflected and refracted compoents, after a "time boundary" we also should have time-reflected and time-refracted beams. Leave the time-refracted one alone, let's talk about the time-reflected one.
Energy conserves near a spatial boundary, and momentum splits in forward and backward ones (in 1D case we can call them positive and negative). However in time boundary's case, it is momentum that conserves, so we would have energy (equally the frequency) splits. Time-refracted beam of course propagating with a forward time factor of $e^{-i\omega_F t}$, while time-reflected beam propagating with a backward time factor of $e^{-i\omega_B t}$.
With my draft it's easy to find out the difference between spatial and time boundaries.

Keep an aye on the reflected wavepackets, especially their shape. The spatial-reflected wavepacket is like "turning back and going forward alone backward direction", while the time-reflected wavepacket is just reversing backward.
It's my first question here so if I'm not explaining well you can have a look of these articles:

https://doi.org/10.1038/s41567-023-01975-y
https://doi.org/10.1038/nphys3810
https://doi.org/10.1038/s41566-023-01290-1

So here's the point, what does this backward time factor mean physicaly? Does it have a negative frequency $\omega_B$? What does a negative frequency mean actually?

This video from Don Lincoln of FermiLab doesn't answer your question, but it is worth a look. It is pretty funny. Are time crystals real?

Yeah I like the way they make complex things much more intresting. Time Crystal is cool and it's the very start of my obsession in time domain, although it has nothing to do with Photonic Time Crystal (Yeah they have very similar name, I found this while searching for Time Crystal papers) that I'm studying now.
